Movie that starts with a bleeding child walking trough the streets
Years ago, I'd say at least 7-8, my dad started watching a movie while I was supposed to go to bed.
The intro scene showed a child walking trough a street while blood was dripping on/near his shoes. As far as I remember you didn't get to see his face, but mostly his feet.
This I am not sure about, but the last thing I remember seeing is that a car pulled over because the driver saw the kid.
As a kid, I was curious and started asking questions about what had happened to the child. My dad told me that fireworks wounded him. I realize now he might've said so just to stop me from asking so I'd go to bed. After all he saw just as much of the movie as I did at that point. Maybe he had already seen it before though. If he did, the fireworks thing might actually be true.
I know I'm not giving a whole lot of information about the movie, but I think that if you know it you'll know what I'm talking about.

Arlington Road, a 1999 thriller about a terrorist bomb plot, starts with exactly this scene. 
Michael Faraday notices the wounded child (the injuries indeed were caused by fireworks) and gets him to the hospital. This way he gets to know the father of the child

who later drags him into an attempt to plant a bomb in an FBI building.


That's fast. It's the one I was talking about. I looked it up and it does show his face. I did remember that wrong. Thanks a lot!
